# Passportjs Google OAuth20 not working when deployed on digital ocean

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js

I have set up a server on the digital ocean and deployed my react application on it. But somehow my Passportjs Google OAuth is not working, but it is working fine when I run it locally, it redirects to callback URL perfectly.

I thought the problems were of node version but I updated node on the server too but still didn't solve.Node -v is 10.15

```js
passport.serializeUser((id, done) => {
  done(null, done)
})

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: keys.google.clientID,
    clientSecret: keys.google.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: prod ? 'http://knowankit.com/myself-in-detail' : 'http://knowankit.com/myself-in-detail'
  }, (request, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    console.log('Testing ')
    done(null, true)
  })
)
```

The website is https://knowankit.com. Login screen - https://knowankit.com/know-me. When you click on user-lock icon it redirects to google login after login it redirects to the homepage. Any help would be really appreciated. I have been stuck on this for a month.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: No, I am not getting errors, You can also check the website link. It might help you to debug.

Comment: this `http://knowankit.com/myself-in-detail` URL is redirecting to the home page.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem, although when I run it in the local environment it works. Not sure where I am doing wrong.

Comment: are you checking anything on route `myself-in-detail` like token or something.

Comment: Yes,   server.get('/myself-in-detail', passport.authenticate('google'), (req, res) => {
    return app.render(req, res, '/ankit', req.query)
  }). I am returning ankit as a component to render.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this. This was my mistake as in the Google OAuth the `localhost:3000` was added as trusted URL but when it is deployed then deployed URL also needs to be added as trusted URL